# Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart : fastclick warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, fastclick.js

I'm having the first popup on which another popup comes to select few fields.
To show the second popup this is the code I'm trying:

```
$("#select1").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //$('#sellerModal').hide();
  var tmplData = {
    string:['Ready','2-3 Days','4-5 Days','1 Week','10+ Days']
  };
  $("#countTypePopupTemplate").tmpl(tmplData).appendTo(".maindiv");
  that.closePopup();
  $("#count_div").each(function() {
    $("#count_div").click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $("#select1").text($(this).text());
      $("#myCounttype").remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML template:

```
<script id="countTypePopupTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div id="myCounttype" class="popup1 layer-2">
    <div class="popup5">
      {{each string}}
      <div id="count_div" class="popup4 bottom-border">${$value}</div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

I'm getting a warning:

```
Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example, because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted. fastclick.js
```

Here I'm not able to click the 4 out of 5 elements in the second popup. Only first 1 is clickable. 
Snapshot of second popup.

[image]

I read all the blogs where the topic is disscussed. But didn't got any solution working for me. Looks like there is some corner case.

Comment: try to change `click` event to `touchstart` with using http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: that also I tried... didn't worked... thanks for the response

Comment: your `each` function is just pointing to the button  of  ***id*** which makes you cannot click other buttons, try to use class and `$(this).click` in `each`. eg `$(".pop_btns").each(function(){$(this).click(function(){ alert($(this).text()); })});`

Comment: if you using phone to do debugging, try to use chrome (android) or safari (iOS) in your computer. Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/  Safari: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: is that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using some parent selector before `$("#count_div").each(function() {
    $("#count_div").click(function(evt) {`
Like this `$(".parent_class #count_div").each(function() {
    $(".parent_class #count_div").click(function(evt) {`

This will solve 1 time running `each()` for `"#count_div"`.

So the actual problem is `each()` is running only 1 time, that's why your first element that is `Ready` click event is working, not others.

Comment: Looks like the same I did and it worked... thanks for the explanation, it really gave a good understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your each function is pointing to id which makes you cannot click other buttons. You should use class to recognize the buttons.

```
$("#select1").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //$('#sellerModal').hide();
  var tmplData = {
    string:['Ready','2-3 Days','4-5 Days','1 Week','10+ Days']
  };
  $("#countTypePopupTemplate").tmpl(tmplData).appendTo(".maindiv");
  that.closePopup();
  $(".pop_btns").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $("#select1").text($(this).text());
      $("#myCounttype").remove();
    });
  });
});
```

HTML template:

```
<script id="countTypePopupTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div id="myCounttype" class="popup1 layer-2">
    <div class="popup5">
      {{each string}}
      <div id="count_div" class="popup4 bottom-border pop_btns">${$value}</div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```